# Does it make any sense to provide fleqn option twice?

Tags: equations, horizontal-alignment, amsmath

In the following MWE it doesn't seem to make a difference whether I use the `fleqn` option for `amsmath` or not - or *only* for `amsmath`.

```
\documentclass[fleqn]{book}
\usepackage[fleqn]{amsmath}
\begin{document}
From this proposition it will follow, when arithmetical addition has been
defined, that
\[ 1+1=2. \]
\end{document}
```

But maybe I'm missing some subtle differences that can only be seen in more complicated situations.  So, my question is whether the `fleqn` option in `amsmath` is only needed for document classes that don't have such an option themselves or if there's a recommended way to switch `fleqn` on - only in the document class, only in `amsmath`, or in both?

Comment: documentclass options are passed to all packages, so fleqn on amsmath makes no difference

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To expand on David's comment, an argument on the document class is passed to all packages. So

```
\documentclass[foo]{bar}
\usepackage{baz}
\usepackage{bam}
```

and

```
\documentclass[foo]{bar}
\usepackage[foo]{baz}
\usepackage[foo]{bam}
```

and also

```
\documentclass[foo]{bar}
\usepackage[foo]{baz}
\usepackage{bam}
```

are exactly the same in their effect. While

```
\documentclass{bar}
\usepackage[foo]{baz}
\usepackage{bam}
```

passes the `foo` option to `baz` only. There are drawbacks to this, of course: For example, you might want to specify `draft` on the document class to see where overfull boxes are but in the process, it also gets passed to `\usepackage{graphicx}` and the included graphics are excluded.

The bottom line, though, is that a double-specification is functionally the same as putting the option on `\documentclass` only.

As for this particular case, regardless of whether the target document class implements a `fleqn` option or not, `amsmath` completely reimplements all the display math environments in LaTeX with the result that even if the target document class wants to forbid `fleqn`, `amsmath` will override that preference.